# Unable to modify array in C after calloc'd

Tags: c, valgrind

I'm still fairly new to C programming. This is a program that takes in an int array made by pointers (int * instead of int[]) and multiplies each int inside it by 2.

Any int that is over 10 has the additional value carried over and the array will be doubled in size if necessary. So, if I input

{9, 0, 4, 8},

it should produce

{0, 0, 0, 1, 8, 0, 9, 6}

but this program produced {0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 4, 8}.

Valgrind told me after calling the `doubleStorage(...)` function in `multiply(...)`, I get an InvalidRead and InvalidWrite warnings which I assumed was where the problem, stemming after I calloc'd the array to resize it. But I'm not sure how to fix it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int * doubleStorage(int ** array, int initialBlocks);
void printArray(int ** array, int blocks);
int * multiply(int ** array, int multiplier, int blocks);


int main() {
    int sizeOfArr = 4 * sizeof(int);
    int * arr = malloc(sizeOfArr);
    arr[0] = 9;
    arr[1] = 0;
    arr[2] = 4;
    arr[3] = 8;

    arr = multiply(&arr, 2, 4);
    printArray(&arr, 8);

    free(arr);

    return 0;
}

// multiplies each int in array by 2
// has a doubleStorage function to double array size if any multiplied int exceeds 10
int * multiply(int ** array, int multiplier, int blocks) {
    int currentBlocks = blocks;

    for (int i = 0; i < blocks; i++) {
        if ((*array)[i] * multiplier > 10) {
            if (i == 0) {
                *array = doubleStorage(array, currentBlocks);
                currentBlocks *= 2;
            }
            (*array)[i - 1] += 1; /* <-- Valgrind reports InvalidRead and InvalidWrite here*/
        }
        (*array)[i] = (*array)[i] * multiplier % 10;
    }

    return *array;
}

// doubles storage of array and relocates the original ints to the back
// doubleStorage({9, 0, 4, 8}, 4) => {0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 4, 8}
int * doubleStorage(int ** array, int initialBlocks) {
    int * more = realloc(*array, 2 * initialBlocks * sizeof(int));
    if (more == NULL) {
        free(*array);
    } else {
        *array = more;
        for (int i = 0; i < initialBlocks; i++) {
            int num = (*array)[i];
            (*array)[i + initialBlocks] = num;
            (*array)[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    return *array;
}

// prints Array
void printArray(int ** array, int blocks) {
    printf("Array: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < blocks; i++) {
        printf("%d ", (*array)[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: On the first iteration of that loop, when `i==0`, you are accessing `(*array)[-1]` which is surely not what you want.  What were you intending to accomplish with that line?

Comment: Tip: Try not to space out your pointer designators, that is use either `int* x` or `int *x`. You have `int * x` which looks like multiplication.

Comment: @rostrivera19 Why is it needed to double the array?

Comment: Unrelated bug: if the `realloc` fails in `doubleStorage` you will free `*array` but leave it untouched and return its original value.  You probably want to return `NULL` instead, otherwise the caller cannot tell that the function failed and will access freed memory, which is bad.  Likewise your `multiply` function should check that `doubleStorage` actually succeeded.

Comment: @tadman: The array doesn't contain pointers, just integers.  The `int **array` is just a pointer to int, passed by reference.

Comment: @NateEldredge What? Why?! This code is so tangled up on itself it really makes no sense.

Comment: @tadman: So it can be updated by `realloc`.  That's actually a fairly common idiom, e.g. the standard `getline` function uses it, though in this particular instance just returning the new pointer would have been okay too.  There are certainly a number of odd choices in this code, but that bit in particular doesn't seem too outlandish to me.

Comment: Problem solved. Thank you, everyone. And yes, I know my coding skills aren't good and that's why I asked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that, when (or if) your `multiply` function needs to double the array size, then you will have moved the values you want/need to change to the new 'back' of the array.

Thus, the elements referenced by expressions like `(*array)[i]` (or any other using the `i` value inside the `[]`) *will be the wrong ones*! This is noticed by Valgrind when `i` is zero and you try to access `(*array)[i - 1]`; however, it will also be wrong for **every** reference using `i` **after** such a size change.

To fix this, set up a new variable to 'monitor' if/when the size has changed. In the code below (which works as expected, when I tested it), this is called `offset`:

```c
int* multiply(int** array, int multiplier, int blocks)
{
    int currentBlocks = blocks;
    int offset = 0; // This will need to change if we double our array size.
    for (int i = 0; i < blocks; i++) {
        if ((*array)[i + offset] * multiplier > 10) {
            if (i == 0) {
                *array = doubleStorage(array, currentBlocks);
                offset += currentBlocks; // Need to adjust offset following array doubling!
                currentBlocks *= 2;
            }
            (*array)[i - 1 + offset] += 1; // Always add the offset to our "i" value...
        }
        (*array)[i + offset] = (*array)[i + offset] * multiplier % 10; // ...and here, also!
    }
    return *array;
}
```

The code could be made a bit more 'efficient' (perhaps) by having a third variable (say, `p`, where you set `p = i + offset`) but I've tried to keep the changes clear and obvious.

Feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation.